# I asked a question before registering

Tags: support

I asked a questing before registering with stack exchange but this does not show up on my profile after registering. The title was "proper field extensions" and I used the same username as I do now. Is it possible to somehow have this added to my profile? This would give me 16 more reputation points.

Comment: See basic info on merging accounts here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info You might find some useful information in the questions tagged [meta-tag:merge-accounts].

Comment: [Link to the question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912295/proper-field-extensions)